# Оптимизация добавления элементов в контейнер WrapPanel (UWP)

Tags: c#, xaml, оптимизация, uwp

В общем: есть контейнер WrapPanel, из WinRTXamlToolkit.

```
<toolkit:WrapPanel x:Name="catalogue" Background="#CCFF99" />
```

В него программно добавляются image(нужно чтобы они были кликабельны, поэтому они вложены в button):

```cs
Button button = new Button();
            button.Style = image_btn;
            using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
            {
                BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage() { DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical, DecodePixelHeight = 0 };
                bitmap.SetSource(stream);
                Image image = new Image() { Source = bitmap };
                button.Content = image;
            }
                   
            button.Click += File_Click;

            catalogue.Children.Add(button);
            catalogue.UpdateLayout();
```

Все это в методе, вызываемом для каждого файла. Тест показывает, что файлы подаются в него всегда в нужном порядке (т.е. сначала добавляется файл1, файл2 и т.д.). Тем не менее, в контейнере предметы расположены в произвольном порядке. Каким способом можно упорядочить их в соответствии с порядком добавления?

P.S. Помимо этого, кнопка... Выступает за пределы картинки - достаточно сильно, чтобы выглядеть непривлекательно. Как можно пофиксить?

[image: Черная обводка - и есть Button. В идеале - хотелось бы вообще сделать ее фон незаметным, а обводку сделать Border'ом]

Черная обводка - и есть Button. В идеале - хотелось бы вообще сделать ее фон незаметным, а обводку сделать Border'ом

UPD: Проблемы указанные выше я решил. В общем, создание кнопок происходило асинхронно - легкие картинки грузились быстрее, тяжелые - медленнее. Собственно, тут и всплыла другая проблема - если добавлять файлы синхронно - программа грузит их долго (некоторые - более чем 0.5 секунд). Я думаю, что нужно загружать их в приложение асихронно, а после синхронно добавлять в контейнер...  Но с этим возникают сложности:
(Я отметил методы, тормозящие программу, комментариями "//!!!")

```cs
public MainPage parent;

//решил хранить сразу "собранные" кнопки, с изображением и бордером на них
//на каждой вкладке TabView будет каталог. Массив кнопок - состав одного каталога. 
        List<Button[]> AllFiles; 

        private WrapPanel catalogue; //контейнер для этих кнопок

        private string filter; //команда на выборку из БД
        public TabsPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();

            AllFiles = new List<Button[]>();
            AllFiles.Add(new Button[0]); //нулевая вкладка - пустая
        }

        public async void UpdateFileList()
        {
            TabViewItem tab = (TabViewItem)tabs.SelectedItem;
            ScrollViewer scroll = (ScrollViewer)tab.Content;
            Grid grid = (Grid)scroll.Content;
            catalogue = (WrapPanel)grid.Children[0];
            catalogue.Children.Clear();

            using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(parent.connectionString))
            {
                connection.ConnectionString = parent.connectionString;
                connection.Open();

                string command = filter;
                try //если массив есть - затирает его
                {
                    AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex] = new Button[getFilesCount(filter_cnt)]; 
//возвращает кол-во файлов по фильтру
                }
                catch //иначе - делает новый
                {
                    AllFiles.Add(new Button[getFilesCount(filter_cnt)]);
//возвращает кол-во файлов по фильтру
                }

                using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int index = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
//!!!
//Именно этот злосчастный метод откликается до 500 мс
                            await AddFileToList(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString().Trim(), index, reader[3].ToString());
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
//это чудо выполняется почти мгновенно
                LoadFiles();

            }
        }
      
        private async Task AddFileToList(string filename, string foldername, int index, string position)
        {
            string[] folders = foldername.Split('/');
            StorageFolder folder = parent.folder;

                for(int i = 0; i < folders.Length && folders[i] != "" ; i++)
                {
                    folder = await folder.GetFolderAsync(folders[i]);
                }
            StorageFile file = await folder.GetFileAsync(filename);
//код выше - ищет файл по вложенный папкам. Быстро.
            Border border = new Border() { BorderThickness = new Thickness(5), BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black) };
            BitmapImage bitmap = new BitmapImage() { DecodePixelType = DecodePixelType.Logical, DecodePixelHeight = 0 };

            Button button = new Button();

//В галерее хранятся и видео, нужно отображать их превью
            if (file.FileType == ".mp4")
            {
//!!!
//Этот ужас и тормозит весь метод. 
                using (var thumbnail = await getThumbnail(file))
                    bitmap.SetSource(thumbnail);
button.Click += image_btn_click;
            }
            else
            {
                using (var stream = await file.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.Read))
                    bitmap.SetSource(stream);

                    button.Click += image_btn_click;
            }

            Image image = new Image() { Source = bitmap};
            image.Width = Double.NaN; ;
            image.Height = 300;
            border.Child = image;
          
            button.Style = image_btn;
            button.Background = null;
            button.Name = file.Path;


            button.Content = border;

            AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex][index] = button;
        }

        private void LoadFiles()
        {
            foreach (Button v in AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex])
            {
                catalogue.Children.Add(v);
                catalogue.UpdateLayout();
            }
        }

//Делает превью. Без него никак, хранить отдельным файлом - не вариант.
        private async Task<IRandomAccessStream> getThumbnail(StorageFile file)
        {
            var mediaClip = await MediaClip.CreateFromFileAsync(file);

            var mediaComposition = new MediaComposition();
            mediaComposition.Clips.Add(mediaClip);

            return await mediaComposition.GetThumbnailAsync(
                TimeSpan.Zero, 0, 0, VideoFramePrecision.NearestFrame);
        }
```

Предполагаю, что беда в неправильном понимании логики async/await... И неправильном их использовании. Подсобите с оптимизацией, прошу!

UPD:
Ух! Всего час практического изучения стоит целого семестра лекций)
В общем, метод, взаимодействующий с бд запустил через Task

```cs
await Task.Run(()=> UpdateFileList());
```

Кнопки создаются сразу, вместе с массивом. Для взаимодействия с UI-потоком использую Dispatcher.RunAsync

```cs
try
                {
                    AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex] = new Button[getFilesCount(filter_cnt)];

                }
                catch
                {
                    AllFiles.Add(new Button[getFilesCount(filter_cnt)]);
                }
                await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                {
                    for (int i = 0; i < AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex].Length; i++)
                    {
                        Button button = new Button();
                        button.Style = image_btn;
                        button.Background = null;
                        catalogue.Children.Add(button);
                        AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex][i] = button;
                    }
                });
using (SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(command, connection))
                {
                    using (SqlDataReader reader = comm.ExecuteReader())
                    {
                        int index = 0;
                        while (reader.Read())
                        {
                            await Dispatcher.RunAsync(Windows.UI.Core.CoreDispatcherPriority.Normal, async () =>
                            {
                                await AddFileToList(reader[0].ToString(), reader[1].ToString().Trim(), index, reader[3].ToString());
                            });
                            index++;
                        }
                    }
                }
```

В конце ранее "злосчастного" метода вызывается ивент

```cs
            SetImage.Invoke(border, index, type);
```

Который одноименным методом цепляет картинку к кнопочке

```cs
private delegate void Handler(Border border, int index, int type);
        private event Handler SetImage;
private void setImage(Border border,int index,int type)
        {
            Button button = AllFiles[tabs.SelectedIndex][index];
            switch (type)
            {
                case 11:
                    border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Purple);
                    button.Click += video_btn_click;
                    break;
                case 12:
                    border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Violet);
                    button.Click += video_story_btn_click;
                    break;
                case 21:
                    border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.BlueViolet);
                    button.Click += image_story_btn_click;
                    break;
                case 22:
                    border.BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Windows.UI.Colors.Black);
                    button.Click += image_btn_click;
                    break;
            }
            button.Content = border;

        }
```

Comment: Вообще стилями в xaml это делается. Вам бы привязки данных `x:Bind` освоить, а не ленты кода писать для того что UWP и так уже умеет.

Comment: @aepot Да, стили я вплетаю, помаленьку. Тут скорее... Вопрос в незнании элементов управления - проблема обводки действительно решилась добавлением border'a, но, вопреки моим ожиданиям, не button.borderbrush, а отдельным контролом <Border>, в который я поместил image (а кнопке сделал прозрачный фон).